# 更新ボタンを押すとニュースを読み込むアプリを作っているのですが、アプリを開いた瞬間にニュースを読み込むようにするにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var entries = NSMutableArray()

    let newsUrlStrings = [
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www3.nhk.or.jp/rss/news/cat0.xml&num=8",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www3.nhk.or.jp/rss/news/cat6.xml&num=8",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www3.nhk.or.jp/rss/news/cat7.xml&num=8"
        ]

    let imageNames = [
    "japan.jpg",
    "world.jpg",
    "sport.jpg",
    ]

    @IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
        entries.removeAllObjects()


        for newsUrlString in newsUrlStrings{

            var url = NSURL(string: newsUrlString)!
            var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, respinse, error in

                var dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

                if var responseData = dict["responseData"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if var feed = responseData["feed"] as? NSDictionary {
                        if var entries = feed["entries"] as? NSArray {

                            var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                            formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en-US")
                            formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"

                            for var i = 0; i < entries.count; i++ {
                                var entry = entries[i] as! NSMutableDictionary

                                entry["url"] = newsUrlString

                                var dateStr = entry["publishedDate"] as! String
                                var date = formatter.dateFromString(dateStr)
                                entry["date"] = date
                            }

                            self.entries.addObjectsFromArray(entries as[AnyObject])

                            self.entries.sortUsingComparator({ object1, object2 in

                            var date1 = object1["date"] as! NSDate
                            var date2 = object2["date"] as! NSDate

                            var order = date1.compare(date2)

                                if order == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
                                    return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
                                }
                                else if order == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending{
                                    return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
                                }

                                return order
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }



                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    })
                })


            task.resume()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
        section: Int) -> Int {
        return entries.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("news") as! UITableViewCell

        var entry = entries[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

        var titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        titleLabel.text = entry["title"] as? String

        var descriptionLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        descriptionLabel.text = entry["contentSnippet"] as? String

        var urlString = entry["url"] as! String
        var index = find(newsUrlStrings, urlString)
        var imageName = imageNames[index!]
        var image = UIImage(named: imageName)

        var imageView = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = image
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: entries[indexPath.row])
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
        if segue.identifier == "detail" {
            var detailController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailController

                    detailController.entry = sender as! NSDictionary
                }
            }
}
```

こうなっています。
タイトルの通り、アプリを開いた瞬間にニュース記事を読み込みたいとき、どうすればいよいのでしょうか

Answer (score 3):

「アプリがバックグラウンドからフォアグラウンドに変わるときに読み込み処理を実行したい」という意図であると理解しました。

その場合、「アプリがフォアグランドに移行した」ことをイベントで取得する必要があります。これは、2つの方法があります。ひとつはAppDelegateにある applicationWillResignActive: が実行されるのでそのタイミングで更新を掛ける方法。もう一つはNSNotificationCenter を使って通知を受け取る方法です。

http://crunchtimer.jp/blog/technology/ios/700/

その他のアプリのライフサイクルについては以下のURLを参考にしてください。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/glass-_-onion/20100630/1277909762

Answer (score 2):

以下のようにviewWillAppearメソッドを追加して実行してみてください。
`viewWillAppear`は画面が表示される直前に実行されるライフサイクルイベントになります。

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    refresh() // 読込実行
}
```

モバイルアプリの開発を進めていくうえで、必ずViewのライフサイクルの理解が必要になります。
ライフサイクルは上記`viewWillAppear`以外にも様々あり、用途やタイミングによって使い分けることが必要になってきます。

以下に素晴らしい記事へのリンクを載せておきます。ご覧になってみてください。

[Viewのライフサイクル](http://qiita.com/yamagh/items/8a7cf2cabf4da3ea471a)

Comment: うまく動かないですね。。。
どの部分に追加するといいでしょうか、

Comment: `viewDidLoad`の下に挿入してみてください。

追記ですが、`refresh`メソッドはIBActionですので、`refresh`メソッド内の処理を新規メソッドにして、ボタンクリック?だけではなく、コード内からの呼び出しにも対応させる必要があります。
すみません、`refresh()`などと回答して言葉足らずだったかもしれません。

Comment: `viewWillAppear`に記述してしまうと、アプリを開いた時だけでなく他画面から戻った際にも実行されてしまいませんか？
そして『アプリを開いた瞬間』が『アプリがフォアグラウンドへ遷移したタイミング』を指しているとすると、新規起動時は`viewWillAppear`が呼び出されますがバックグラウンドからの復帰時では呼び出されない場合があります。
なので、`viewWillAppear`内での実装は今回のケースの場合、色々と制御が難しい気がします。